# Stunnel internal error message

Tags: stunnel

I get the stunnel error message:

> INTERNAL ERROR: Bad magic at /home/ASchulma/dev/cygwin/stunnel/stunnel-4.49-1/s 6 [sig] stunnel 3920 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to stunnel.exe.stackdump

at the end of a trial of either reading or sending email.  Although the trial of reading or sending email was successful, this error message occurs.  I could ignore it, but I'd like to understand its meaning.  Can anyone explain its significance?

I now provide more detail.  My platform is a Dell Latitude D531 laptop running Windows XP Home.  For stunnel I was using the [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) version.  For reading email I was using [View Mail](http://www.nongnu.org/viewmail/), from Emacs 23 (GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (`i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600`) of 2011-03-10 on 3249CTO).  My server choice was `pop.gmail.com:995`.

In the trial of sending email I was using server `smtp.gmail.com:465`.  I used "stunnel" from Cygwin in the same manner that View Mail uses it to connect to e.g. a POP server. I modified function "smtpmail-via-smtp" in "smtpmail.el" (Emacs 23.3 distribution) so that it uses "stunnel" in this manner.

In both cases (reading or sending email) the error occurs right after the QUIT command is issued to the server.